# How would you know if you maxed out EVs on one stat or for all?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I already know that the max EV points a pokemon gets is 510, and that the max for a stat is 252 so you get 252 for 2 stats and 6 on another.

Question is, how do I know if I maxed out a stat already?(Im using emerald by the way) so does the Ribbon girl give you a ribbon if you have 510 or if one of your stats as 255? How do I know when to EV train the other stat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ribbon Girl will give you the ribbon if when you have 510 EVs total. The thing is, you don't know when you've maxed out a stat. If you're going for a specific EV amount, you'll want to clear all your EVs with the EV resetting berries (Pomeg, Kelpsy, Qualot, Hondew, Grepa, Tamato), and keep track yourself.

Of course, if you're just going to max two stats, you can overkill with the EV training in one stat (ensuring that it is maxed), and then work on the other one.

Comment: erk either that or i keep track of my evs one by one right? ugh. anyways thanks, ill try to do the overkill training